# Can't publish package to npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I can't publish public package to npm. I have created organization but i cant find a way how to add new package.

Thanks for help
[image]

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/packages-and-modules/contributing-packages-to-the-registry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add a new package from the command line. Just do

- `npm init`  (to create `package.json` with details)
- `npm login`
- `npm publish`

See [npm-publish](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/publish) for details, but if you just try to publish it should notify you what needs to be done.

Comment: @barron Just try it and report back should it not be sufficient. I have published loads of packages. Also, try to namespace them under your user by changing the `name` property in `package.json` to `@barron/my-package`.

Comment: yes working thanks i have published react-native-pickerlist@0.0.1